# Nomalization error "Interpolation of X points outside the convex hull"

Tags: r, lidar, lidr, normalize

Recently I had to update my version of `lidR` from 2.3 to 3.0 and since then, the script I had for normalizing my files can not finish the process not even if I indicate `opt_stop_early()<-FALSE`. The code I am using:

```r
# Function that filters all LAS files 
ground_filter = function(chunk)
{
  las = readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
   
  ground <- filter_ground(las)               
  
  if (is.empty(ground)) {return(NULL)} # if no ground points are found returns NULL

  lasnorm <- normalize_height(las, tin())
  lasnorm <- filter_poi(lasnorm, buffer == 0) # eliminate buffer area before exporting
  return(lasnorm) # if ground points are found returns normalized data
}
  
opt_chunk_size(ctg_0) <- 0  # needs to be 0 to process file by file 
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg_0) <- 100 # needs to be >0 to avoid edge artifacts
opt_filter(ctg_0) <- "-keep_first -keep_class 1 2 3 4 5" # only read poits classified as 1 2 3 4 5 (noise=class 7)
opt_output_files(ctg_0) <- paste(dz_export, "*_dz", sep = "") # export in directory
opt_stop_early(ctg_0) <- FALSE
opt_laz_compression(ctg_0) <- TRUE  # output has .LAZ format
  
# Creates a list of files with ground points
output <- catalog_apply(ctg_0, ground_filter)
norm <- catalog(unlist(output))
```

The process is carried out looking normal with some messages that say  `Interpolation of X points outside the convex hull defined by ground points (outside the triangulation) failed and returned NAs`.

```
Chunk 202 of 206 (98.5%): state ⚠
Chunk 203 of 206 (99%): state ⚠
Interpolation of 462 points outside the convex hull defined by ground points (outside the triangulation) failed and returned NAs.
Chunk 204 of 206 (99.5%): state ✗
Interpolation of 462 points outside the convex hull defined by ground points (outside the triangulation) failed and returned NAs.
Error: 462 points were not normalizable. Process aborted.
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Execution halted
```

The normalization is just the beginning of a whole process and after the normalization is finished the process is stopped. How can I avoid these errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is normalize\_height() function aborting in lidR?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366520/why-is-normalize-height-function-aborting-in-lidr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `na.rm = TRUE` in `normalize_height()`. The problematic points are likely to be in the buffer anyway. Also in version 3.0.3 `tin()` enables to control on how interpolation is extrapolated outside the ground points. Check the doc. What changed recently is that it no longer extrapolates for points that are too far from any ground point (50 m) because it is abnormally far. You can change that. But first you should look at your point cloud and check why you have non ground point so far away from any ground point. See also [this related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366520/why-is-normalize-height-function-aborting-in-lidr).

Comment: Please, add the [tag:lidar] tag in [tag:lidR] questions as well, specially when there are available slots (5 tags are allowed per question). It is not rare people working with LiDAR data are searching for a solution/way to accomplish tasks/goals without being tied to a software. So it is **not** unlikely people will consider your answers useful even if they were not working with R until then. This will also bring even more visibility to your package, and will return reputation points, which is good because you earn privileges with them (and can help us moderate content here). Tks.