# Fix point cloud lidR - normalize_height fails

Tags: lidar, lidr

I'm working on an airborne lidar survey of around a thousand tiles (500m * 500m) using `LAScatalog` with `lidR`. I firstly ran a `las_check()`... No issues reported:

```r
las_check(CTG_Bertrix)

#>  Checking headers consistency
#>   - Checking file version consistency... ✓
#>   - Checking scale consistency... ✓
#>   - Checking offset consistency... ✓
#>   - Checking point type consistency... ✓
#>   - Checking VLR consistency... ✓
#>   - Checking CRS consistency... ✓  
#>  Checking the headers
#>   - Checking scale factor validity... ✓
#>   - Checking Point Data Format ID validity... ✓  
#>  Checking preprocessing already done 
#>   - Checking negative outliers... ✓
#>   - Checking normalization... no  
#>  Checking the geometry
#>   - Checking overlapping tiles... ✓
#>   - Checking point indexation... yes
```

After this initial check, I still ran `filter_duplicates()` and after ran a `normalize_height()` process which actually failed:

```r
#> An error occurred when processing the chunk 998. Try to load this chunk with:  chunk <-
#> readRDS("C:\Users\gef\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWK6Gyw/chunk998.rds") 
#> las <- readLAS(chunk) 3044 points were not normalizable. Process aborted.
```

I loaded the considered chunk and ran again `las_check()`:

```r
#>  Checking the data
#>   - Checking coordinates... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinates type... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinates range... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinates quantization... ✓
#>   - Checking attributes type... ✓
#>   - Checking ReturnNumber validity... ✓
#>   - Checking NumberOfReturns validity... ✓
#>   - Checking ReturnNumber vs. NumberOfReturns... ✓
#>   - Checking RGB validity... ✓
#>   - Checking absence of NAs... ✓
#>   - Checking duplicated points... ✓
#>   - Checking degenerated ground points... ✓
#>   - Checking attribute population...
#>      'EdgeOfFlightline' attribute is not populated
#>   - Checking gpstime incoherances
#>     ✗ 1263 pulses (points with the same gpstime) have points with identical ReturnNumber
#>   - Checking flag attributes... ✓
#>   - Checking user data attribute... ✓  
#>  Checking the header
#>   - Checking header completeness... ✓
#>   - Checking scale factor validity... ✓
#>   - Checking point data format ID validity... ✓
#>   - Checking extra bytes attributes validity... ✓
#>   - Checking the bounding box validity... ✓
#>   - Checking coordinate reference system... ✓  
#>  Checking header vs data adequacy
#>   - Checking attributes vs. point format... ✓
#>   - Checking header bbox vs. actual content... ✓
#>   - Checking header number of points vs. actual content... ✓
#>   - Checking header return number vs. actual content... ✓  
#>  Checking coordinate reference system...
#>   - Checking if the CRS was understood by R... ✓  
#>  Checking preprocessing already done 
#>   - Checking ground classification... yes
#>   - Checking normalization... no
#>   - Checking negative outliers... ✓
#>   - Checking flightline classification... yes
```

This las file can be downloaded [HERE](https://filesender.belnet.be/?s=download&token=56bb9681-a956-40fa-a72e-39f37648cff6)...

As the error message is not really self-explanatory, I would like to know how to find the not normalizable points? How to fix/remove them ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. What are the two files you linked? You said that one is weird and the other one is normal but don't know the difference between the two files. One seems to be the chunk saved by the processing engine after crashing the other one is...? Please clarify

Comment: Yes that's it. One is the chunk loaded as suggested by the error message and the other is the orginal tile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has already been asked here at least twice. One occurrence [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366520/why-is-normalize-height-function-aborting-in-lidr).

```r
library(lidR)
las = readLAS("bertrix.laz")
normalize_height(las, tin())
#> Interpolation of 3044 points outside the convex hull defined by ground points (outside the triangulation) failed and returned NAs.
#> Erreur : 3044 points were not normalizable. Process aborted. 

plot(las, color = "Classification")
```

[image]

As you can see, on the top right you have a building with no ground points at all. All the points are too far from a ground point to allow interpolation especially with TIN. You have three options.

1. Discard those points `normalize_height(las, tin(), na.rm = TRUE)` but I don't think it is a good idea
2. Use a much larger buffer to catch more ground point after the building. e.g. 80 meters `opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) = 80`
3. Allow interpolation where TIN is not defined even if it's far (e.g. 100 meters) `normalize_height(las, tin(extrapolate = knnidw(rmax = 100)))`

In all cases interpolation in region with no ground point is relatively weak

Comment: Thanks. The raster I/O issue posted few days ago was also related to this issue. The process failed but still produced a lascatalog (buggy one for my case)

Comment: Maybe the error message could be more explicit for users and points to this (very likely) issue?

Comment: The error is properly handled with an informative error `Interpolation of 3044 points outside the convex hull defined by ground points (outside the triangulation) failed and returned NAs`. The issue is annoying but it is the user responsibility to choose how to perform interpolation where it is not interpolable. I don't think it is a good idea to treat it silently.